# Switch Activities Without Changing the Background - Android

Tags: android

I'm just wondering, is it possible to switch between activities without changing the background?

Maybe something like, Adding a big size background behind all activities and set the activities background to transparent. Is it possible to do it?

---

In addition, I want that if I put slide transition between activities, I want the background to stay still while the other component like textfield, button, etc do the transition.
Is it possible to do it?

Comment: use one root layout in all xml files with same background.

Comment: Hi Ketan, if I put the transition animation between activities, the background will also "animate". Is it possible to prevent that? I mean, only the objects (textview, textfield, etc) within the activity will do the transition animation, not the background

Comment: please have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765420/keeping-the-same-background-across-multiple-activities-in-android-and-excluding)

Answer (score 0):

How you can achieve this?

1) Create BaseActivity which extends Activity

2) Your all activity will extends BaseActivity

3) In your BaseActivity override setContentView() method

```
@Override
    public void setContentView(int resId) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(resId, getContentView());
        this.setContentView(getContentView());
    }

private LinearLayout getContentView() {

            LinearLayout contentView = new LinearLayout(this);
            contentView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
            contentView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    convertView.setBackGround(); // your common background for all activities

        return contentView;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Biraj, I've got error in "private LinearLayout..." line. Does that linearlayout requires certain package? It says "LinearLayout cannot be resolved into type". Also, you have extra closing bracket in the bottom line which seems to generate error.

Answer (score 0):

You can can add a theme that will be the background to all screens in the application.

```
<application android:theme="@style/MyTheme"....>
 //all activities
</application>
```